# httpd multiple websites with physical and virtual hosting on apache with centos 6.4

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

I have set up website in apache on server.example.com domain. It was working fine.
Then I set up virtual host on www.example.com domain. The moment I completed configuration of virtual host and restarted httpd, both server.example.com and www.example.com started pointing to virtual host website. I am not sure what am i missing. Why my physical host website stopped working?

Is it not possible to host two websites one on physical host and other on virtual? Do i have to set up both of them on virtual hosts?